# Как компилируется динамическая библиотека .so?

Tags: c++, c, библиотеки, elf

Правильно ли я понимаю, что в секции .plt находится адрес вызываемой функции из  динамической библиотеки и в момент выполнения происходит, переход по тому адресу, где скомпонована библиотека, и выполнение, или она копируется в запущенный процесс именно во время выполнения?

Comment: Вообще-то, адреса находятся в GOT, а PLT состоит из небольших секций кода, обеспечивающих косвенный переход к вызываемой функции. Все это подробно описано [тут](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/03/position-independent-code-pic-in-shared-libraries)